# Hyperledger composer: calling a query within a transaction that updated an asset returns old results

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have a problem with a very simple Hyperledger Composer applicationnamespace com.softwaremill.drivernetwork

```
participant Driver identified by licenseId {
  o String licenseId
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
  o Boolean licenseValid default =true
}

enum LaweEnforcerType {
  o POLICE
  o CUSTOMS
  o BORDER_GUARDS
}

participant LawEnforcer identified by lawEnforcerId {
  o String lawEnforcerId
  o LaweEnforcerType lawEnforcerType
}

participant Court identified by courtId {
  o String courtId
  o String description
}

enum FineState {
  o ISSUED
  o REJECTED
  o ACCEPTED
}

asset Fine identified by fineId {
  o String fineId
  o Integer penaltyPoints
  o DateTime date
  o FineState fineState default ="ISSUED"
  --> Driver driver
  --> LawEnforcer lawEnforcer
}

asset CourtCase identified by caseId {
  o String caseId
  --> Court court optional
  --> Fine fine
}

transaction AcceptedFine {
  --> Fine fine
}

transaction RejectedFine {
  --> Fine fine
}
```

LawEnforcer can issue a Fine. The Fine can be either Accepted or Rejected (then it goes to Court) by the driver.

What I am trying to do is to automatically invalidate the driver's license if the sum of all his accepted `penaltyPoints` on Fines exceeds 20 points.

So I have created a transaction processor

```
/**
 * Accept fine
 * @param {com.softwaremill.drivernetwork.AcceptedFine} acceptedFine
 * @transaction
 */
async function acceptedFine(acceptedFine) {
    console.log(`Accepting fine ${acceptedFine}`);

    const fineRegistry = await     getAssetRegistry('com.softwaremill.drivernetwork.Fine');

    acceptedFine.fine.fineState = 'ACCEPTED';
    await fineRegistry.update(acceptedFine.fine); // [1]

    const allFines = await query('selectAcceptedFinesByDriver', 
    {driver: `resource:com.softwaremill.drivernetwork.Driver#${acceptedFine.fine.driver.licenseId}`}); // [2]

    if (allFines.reduce((acc, val) => {return acc + val.penaltyPoints;}, 0) > 20) {
        console.log('Driver excceded 20 points, blocking license');

        const driverRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('com.softwaremill.drivernetwork.Driver');

        acceptedFine.fine.driver.licenseValid = false;

        await driverRegistry.update(acceptedFine.fine.driver);
    }
}
```

And the query code

```
query selectAcceptedFinesByDriver {
  description: "Select all accepted fines for a given driver"
  statement:
    SELECT com.softwaremill.drivernetwork.Fine
      WHERE (driver == _$driver AND fineState == "ACCEPTED")
}
```

Now the code should set the Fine state to `ACCEPTED` at `[1]`. This works - after the transaction is processed I am able to see the property changed.

But the problem is that at `[2]` when the query is executed the Fine that just got updated at `[1]` has still status `ISSUED` (I've removed the right part of where in the query to debug it).

What am I missing here? Is the shape of the blockchain someone frozen for the transaction? What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the issue is that you can't "read your own writes". Transactions are atomic (so all of the states being changed in one transaction get committed as one transaction, from the current state, or - the whole transaction gets rejected.

So the 'state' that you're reading (in the query) is the known state from the last committed state (this present transaction is not committed yet, so `[2]` couldn't possibly get the 'ACCEPTED' state at that point. This behaviour in Composer is exactly the same behaviour that you get from the underlying Hyperledger Fabric blockchain ; a `GetState`(query) will only read committed state changes, and not data (in the current transaction) written by a previous `PutState` (prior update in the same transaction). The query would only work (in this case) if that transaction is already committed ie by the organisations' peers that endorse/commit the transaction (atomic transaction) to a block (and the world state).

You can read more on transaction processors here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts

Comment: Thanks! That's what I kinda expected. Probably my mindset is too much in the SQL world :) In this very simple example it's kinda easy what to do - just all the query and add the processed fine's penaltyPoints from the transaction - but do you have any suggestions what would be the kosher way of dealing with similar cases on a larger scale?

Comment: Do you need to update the Driver individually, after the fine has been committed to the ledger? My suggestion would be to have a separate transaction (using your query, to find all Drivers exceeding your threshold) - and you can - as one atomic transaction - 'batch' up all of the 'Driver' updates in the same registry - as one transaction (which is obviously more scalable). There is an example of this (using a query, to execute a 'batch' removal) in the sample-networks here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/lib/logic.js#L39

Comment: If you need some sample code for your example, let me know. You'll basically create a similar `for` or `forEach` loop then do an `update` etc and its all one atomic transaction unit

Comment: So you would suggest to call that other transaction from a cronjob or something like that?

Comment: you could do that (you'll know the urgency of those updates). Using `composer transaction submit` eg `composer transaction submit -c taskadmin@driver-network  -d '{"$class":"com.softwaremill.drivernetwork.AcceptedFine"}' ` etc

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating Fine state on the asset, you are doing it only on submitted Transaction.

You need to update it on asset similar to how your are updating licenseValid status.